# View GitHub PR comments locally in PhpStorm

Tags: github, phpstorm

I generate a pull request in the company repo on GitHub. My colleagues login to GitHub, review my changes and add comments.

Is there a way from me to pull those comments (or that PR) from GitHub so I can read and, ideally respond to their comments locally from within the latest PhpStorm (version 2017.3.4) or for that matter, from the CLI?

I can see how to generate PRs in PhpStorm and push them up to GH, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10448-github-code-reviews-plugin. In general, this is not yet supported in PhpStorm out of the box, you can vote for that feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85079 and try out some of the suggestion listed there (e.g. the plugin mentioned above).

Comment: That plugin isn't compatible with the current versions of JetBrains IDEs.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, it wasn't updated for 4 years. But the issue was addressed by IntelliJ IDEA team themselves: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85079.

Comment: It's not addressed. I came looking because I still can't see inline code comments in PhpStorm. I only see PR conversation comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's something for Github, but for Bitbucket you can use [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13538-code-review-for-bitbucket/).